# Is there no way to turn off animation in Highcharts for multiple real-time curves?

Tags: highcharts

Following the example I have only added another curve.
If I disable the first curve the the "second" curve won't be animated.
So the problem is when I define multiple series.

https://codepen.io/andl/pen/KKNExod?editors=1010

What I have done to try and disable animations:

```
chart: {
        annimation: false,
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                animation: false
            },
            series: {
                animation: false
            }
        },
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, there's just a typo for `chart.animation` (it's been written as `annimation`):

```js
// Create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  chart: {
    animation: false,
    ...
```